# SMACK 4.1.1 connecting to XMPP server running OpenFire 4.2.3....client connections idle time not working

Tags: timeout, xmpp, openfire

I had the idle time set at 900 seconds (15 mins). (Disconnect clients after they are idle for 900 seconds); the ping was enabled (Send XMPP Ping request to idle clients was ON).

Result: Client connection kept dropping (not even receiving END_DOCUMENT tag on SMACK API) after just a few minutes (typically a minute or two) of establishing connection (that the connection was established was verified from the server portal and from client being able to send chat messages). No ping was ever sent to client prior to disconnect (as was expected).

Updated the idle time to 10 seconds (NO OTHER CHANGE on CLIENT OR SERVER SIDE):
The client got pinged every few seconds (typically every two seconds) and as long as client pongs back, the connection stayed on.

This is puzzling...we set idle connection time high enough so we don't have to swamp the network traffic with ping/pong, I thought..so now I am not sure what the idle time value even means...if anyone can explain this mechanism and why this is happening, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Pleae read tag explanations before using them.  You question has nothing to do with either the Python language or its IDLE IDE.

Comment: Yes indeed, that tag was added accidentally it appears...my bad...thx for deleting it!